# Does Star Wars G canon always beat C canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon

An answer to [this question I posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23521/are-there-any-c-canon-non-game-works-that-have-n-canon-facts/24840#24840) gave me a curiosity in the opposite direction:

Were there any cases where Star Wars movie (G or T) canon was officially overruled by later Extended Universe canon (C)?

Or is G canon always 100% trumping C canon, by definition?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this happened. I'll dig up the reference and post

Comment: Events have overtaken this post. As of April 2014, there's no such thing as either.

Answer (score 6):

[Leland Chee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leland_Chee) (Keeper of the Holocron, and thus pretty much the main authority on canon) confirmed that this did indeed happen.

> (explaining how canon database works) ... Source A contradicts Source B. **More likely than not**, if Source A is from the films and Source B is from the EU, we'll use Source A. **Of course, there can always be exceptions which is why the case-by-case determination is always in effect no matter what the Sources.**" (*[src](http://web.archive.org/web/20070912190342/http://forums.starwars.com/thread.jspa?threadID=152583&start=510)*)

When pressed for details on the same thread, he indicated this (Tasty Taste is his ID on that starwars.com forum):

> From: [Tasty Taste](http://web.archive.org/web/20070827042003/http://forums.starwars.com/profile.jspa?userID=414903)
>   Date Posted: Nov 07, 2005 10:06 AM
>
> > *I'd be interested to know what circumstances would allow the EU to overthrow the films...*
>
> Well, you've got the Boba Fett thing. Then there's stormtroopers where there's a bunch of sources released prior to Ep2 that said that they were human recruits. Hence we established that while most stormtroopers are clones, there are some that are recruits.

Comment: That doesn't say that it *did* ever happen, just that it *could* happen — Did it?

Comment: @jwodder - see the update

Comment: What precisely is "the Boba Fett thing"?

Comment: @Kevin - Boba Fett "died" in Ep 6. (confirmed by Lucas off-screen, not just "seemed to die"). Yet, the EU continuity officially approved that he survived the Sarlacc and had years and years and many books' worth of life left (from Boba Fett trilogy to post-NJO)

Comment: Ah, that. He blew the saarlac up with a thermal detonator and his armor somehow let him survive the blast, right?

Comment: When I worked for my college newspaper, I did an interview with Jeremy Bulloch. He said that Fett had opened a club in Sarlacc's belly and invites other "victims" to join his club.

Comment: @Kevin  I think his *badass-ness* let him survive

Comment: @Kevin - That is addressed in the bounty hunter series.  He was found near death by some other bounty hunter looking to pick up loot from jabba's barge, and nursed back to health.

Comment: @Chad - Dengar. and I didn't even have to look it up. Scary.